# Is there a way to Asymmetrically encrypt access tokens created with Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, jwe

I am building an application which consists of 3 server. The first is my `Authorization server`, the second is my `Database server(API)` and finally my `front-end server`. I want to use asymmetrical encryption to encrypt the access token generated by my `Authorization server` so that sensitive data is not compromised and also so that i can send it along to my `API` and verify that the user making a request is actually who they claim to be. Is there anything in Laravel Passport that will make this implementation possible or is it better to use a third party library like [PASETO](https://github.com/paragonie/paseto) or [PHP JWT Framework](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework)??

Currently when i make a request to the Api

1. The Api makes a call to the `Authorization server` to validate user using the access token.
2. The `Auth server` validates the User
3. If user validates, Api delivers the resources we asked for, else it return a validation error.

What i want to achieve with the Asymmetrical encryption is to eliminate the call to my `Auth server` before every request to the API and i read that i can achieve this using asymmetrical encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem I ended up using the [SimpleJWT](https://github.com/kelvinmo/simplejwt) library to encrypt the data in the access token. The data is encrypted in the JWE claims.

```
  $headers = ['alg' => 'RSA-OAEP-256', 'enc' => 'A128CBC-HS256'];
  $access_token = {"sub": "1234567890", "name": "John Doe", "iat": 1516239022}
  // Creating JWE object with headers and claims
  $jwe = new \SimpleJWT\JWE($headers, $claims);
  $jwe_encrypted = $jwe->encrypt($foreing_server_public_key);
```

I later decrypt the token using the python library [JWCrypto](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I am thinking about making the switch to [Authlib JOSE Guide](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/jose/jwe.html) because it seems to have a broader community and support.

```
//Decrypting JWE
//Private key should be key pair of public key used to encrypt token
jwetoken.deserialize(jwe_encrypted, key=private_key)
//Validating Signature since passport signs tokens when generating them
jwstoken.verify(auth_public_key)
//Payload should contain encrypted data
data = json.loads(jwstoken.payload.decode())
>> {"sub": "1234567890", "name": "John Doe", "iat": 1516239022}
```